# More on Java can't find symbol from .class in the same directory

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac, identifier

I defined 2 java files: Phone2.java and TestPhone2.java. Phone2.java compiles fine and is placed in a package named classes. TestPhone2 is supposed to create an instance of Phone2 but I cannot get TestPhone2.java to compile. Below is my directory structure:

The 2 java files are located here --

[image]

Phone2.class is located inside package `classes` --

[image]

My `classpath` is set to c:\myJavaProject.

The java files contain some simple codes from Mala Gupta to test instance and local variables. Here are the codes:

```
package classes;
class Phone2 {
    String phoneNumber = "123456789";
    void setNumber () {
        String phoneNumber;
        phoneNumber = "987654321";
    }
}


package classes;
class TestPhone2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Phone2 p1 = new Phone2();
        p1.setNumber();
        System.out.println(p1.phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

It is not clear to me why TestPhone2.java failed to compile. I reviewed some stackoverflow posts on this type of error ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303297/java-error-cannot-find-symbol-even-if-the-class-file-are-all-in-the-same-dire) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731088/java-cant-find-symbol-from-class-in-the-same-directory)) but the posts seem not to be directly on point. One of the posts dealt with `static` method and the other dealt with error stemming from an `import` or `package` statement. I don't think there is an error in my package statement because I used a similar package statement earlier today in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852459/classpath-seems-correct-but-jvm-still-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/26852695#26852695) and there was no problem.

Below is my exact keystrokes.

[image]

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Although I respect you wanting to "Rambo" your way through development by hunting for your own food in the jungle etc (ie manually dealing with classpath and build issues), I strongly recommend using an IDE (ie use the McDonands in town)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a package. So you must specify the classpath. One way to do that is to use the folder that contains your top level package (`c:\myJavaProject\tint31\`) like

```
set CLASSPATH=c:\myJavaProject\tint31\
javac -d . TestPhone2.java
```

or you might use `-classpath` like

```
javac -d . -classpath c:\myJavaProject\tint31\ TestPhone2.java
```

Comment: Worked like charm! From Sotirios Delimanolis comment in my post earlier today [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852459/classpath-seems-correct-but-jvm-still-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/26852695#26852695), he had mentioned I need not put `..\mobile` in the `classpath` which in this case translates to `..\tint31`. Now I am confused as to the correct rule of thumb.

Comment: @sedeh Sorry. But no, you changed *mobile* to *classes*. And `C:\myJavaProject` to `C:\myJavaProject\tint31`. Java packages are effectively mapped to directories (or stored as directories stored in archive files based on zip, called jars,ears and/or wars).

Comment: Ok. I see. In this case, I've an additional level in my directory structure. So I need to include the level just before the target folder. In this case, I need to include up to `..\tint31`. Correct?

Comment: @sedeh Unless they have changed the meaning of *worked like [a] charm*. The important thing is you understand it.